# Removing/Adding a specific variable from an object inside javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a map array with objects stuffed with variables looking like this:

```
var map = [
[{ground:0, object:1}, {ground:0, item:2}, {ground:0, object:1, item:2}],
[{ground:0, object:1}, {ground:0, item:2}, {ground:0, object:1, item:2}]
];
```

Now I would like to be able to delete and add one of the variables like `item:2`.

1) What would I use to delete specific variables?

2) What would I use to add specific variables?

I just need 2 short lines of code, the rest like detecting if and where to execute I've figured out.

I've tried `delete map[i][j].item;` with no results.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to remove the entire object {ground:0, object:1}, I want to delete the property, variable, whatever it's called from inside the object that is the key.

Comment: `delete map[i][j].item` should do what you want

Comment: Okej, I've tried that allready, but it doesn't delete it, the rest of the code to be executed at that moment works fine though. Got any clues what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I imagine you're re-assigning the value somewhere else in the code, so by the time you get around to checking it, the value is back

Comment: Sorry I'm retarded, changed [i][j] to X and Y positions and it fixed it, change your post to an answer and you get free credit. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete map[i][j].item` should be what you need. Here's my test run in the Javascript console (Chrome)

```
> var map = [
    [{ground:0, object:1}, {ground:0, item:2}, {ground:0, object:1, item:2}],
    [{ground:0, object:1}, {ground:0, item:2}, {ground:0, object:1, item:2}]
  ];
  undefined

> map[0][1]
  Object
    ground: 0
    item: 2
    __proto__: Object

> delete map[0][1].item
  true

> map[0][1]
  Object
    ground: 0
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: While I got you here, whats the delete version to add something in the same way?

Comment: You're overthinking it. `map[0][1].item = 2` if `item` doesn't already exist, it gets added.